# post message to slack using API

Tags: c#, httpclient, slack-api

I'm trying to post a message to Slack using their API and the response says: `Waiting for activation`

This is my code:

```
static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMessage()
{ 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "xoxb-924542226483-938230541718-gk3vTmwEtOOK01NqO5kW6e0R");
    var atttrJson = new stackAttributes { channel = "#cymulateinterview", text = "Good Morning all" };
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(atttrJson);
    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var result = await client.PostAsync("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", byteContent);
    return result;
}
```

What am I missing

Comment: I haven't worked with Slack's API much, but: at a guess, your app hasn't been activated (maybe approved)?

Comment: nope.haven't worked with Slack at all until yesterday. it seems like I can post messages when using UI. I must be missing something.

Comment: I doubt your problem is Slack related. Maybe it is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551008/task-keeps-waiting-for-activation